# while(true) loop only executes once

Tags: java, while-loop

I wrote a piece of code which should be executed until the condition is satisfied. I have 2 classes using the same structure. In one of them while (true) loop executes as expected; in the other class the program exits the loop after the first recursion.

```
        protected static boolean flag = true;
        private static int value=0;
        private static int limit=10;
        .
        .
        .

        public static int method(){

            if (limit-value <=0)
            {

            ...
            }

            else {
            while(flag) {
                if (limit-value > 0 ) {

                    *the action I want to perform until the condition is satisfied*

                    value++; 

                }

                else if (limit==value)
                {
                    flag = false;
                } 
                return int_Value;
            }

        }
    }
    return int_Value;
}
```

I expect the while(true) loop to be executed until the condition is satisfied (which is more than once).

Comment: Use a debugger to step though the code..

Comment: What's int_Value? I don't see it defined!

Comment: Your code does not contain `while (true)`. Please make sure that the code you post represents your problem accurately.

Comment: @Amadan, a flag is used to set it to true. That's what the OP has done in the code!

Comment: Firstly cannot see int_Value defined anywhere, so that can be an issue, apart from that when you return something from inside the loop will definitely terminates the loop.

Comment: How about providing a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you look at your code the while loop goes like this

```
 while(flag) {
    if (limit-value > 0 ) {

        *the action I want to perform until the condition is satisfied*

             value++; 

    }

    else if (limit==value)
    {
            flag = false;
    } 
    return int_Value;
}
```

after executing either if or if else statement there is a return int_value statement which is causing the problem

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you spot that before or after I applied the indentation cleanup? Looking at how shortly after my answer you posted yours, it could be both...

Comment: well i suspected it when i looked at the code but i re-indented it to conform.

Comment: Always write clean code with proper indentation. that's why i use python, you should try it

Comment: i didn't say i switched because of the indentation.

Comment: i use python for its simplicity. indentation is just a plus :D

Comment: There may be many reasons to switch languages, but forced formatting wouldn't be one of them (imho).

Comment: I can agree to that.

Answer (score 1):

With some cleaned up indentation it becomes clear that the while loop contains an unconditional `return`.

Answer (score 0):

Although I did debugging I couldn't see it in the first place. I performed another debug session after @user3437460 's suggestion, so I was able to find out:

It seems like an additional return statement was used!(return int_Value;),
the one after else if block. So, the program returns a value and never goes back into the loop.
After deleting the first return statement, program runs just fine.

Comment: This is exactly what both existing, older answers point out. Normally making your own answer is appreciated, but in this context it seems weird.